# Alter retention.ms property for kafka topic deletes the old data

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to change the retention.ms property for a existing topic, but as per my analysis it deletes all the existing data inside the topic.

Scenarios:-
Initially my topic name is `"topic1"` with retention as 5 Mins and it contains some data.

Use Case 1 - Change the retention to a higher period
Then i change the retention.ms value to 8 mins by using the below command:-

```
 bin/kafka-topics.sh --alter --zookeeper localhost:2181 
   --topic topic1 --config retention.ms=8
```

But it deletes all my old data from that topic.
After that i pushed some more data into that topic.

Use Case 2 - Change the retention to a lower period
Then i change the retention.ms value to 3 mins by using the below command:-

```
 bin/kafka-topics.sh --alter --zookeeper localhost:2181 
   --topic topic1 --config retention.ms=3
```

It also deletes the previous data that from that topic.

Could someone please tell me the exact behavior for the same.

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

**retention.ms** property in Kafka takes milliseconds. So you are changing retention period to 8 and 3 milliseconds respectively. You have to give 480000 if you want to set 8 mins retention period.

Comment: Yes that's fine. But I need clarity on why it deletes the data in the topic after updation of retention.ms.

Comment: It is deleting data because you data is older than your retention period and this is how retention works.

Comment: Even if it is not older than the retention period, it deletes the data. I tried this kafka stand-alone mode command-line.